# insert statements don't insert nothing but it shows 'query executed successfully'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I have a very long script(about 3000 rows) that fills a database. When I execute it I have the message

QUERY EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY

I counted one table not filled on my pc(on a total of about 20 tables). On my collegue's pc none of the tables are filled.

I am using stored procedures where I put insert statements

No errors are shown

Comment: Don't insert nothing? So they insert something right?

Comment: I left my crystal ball in my other pants. Can you share some details other than "it didn't work"? At the very least the code that doesn't work.

Comment: one table on my pc is not filled. On my collegue's pc none of the tables are filled. There are not errors shows. Only 'query executed successfully'

Comment: @DavidG my main problem now is that tables are not filled on other PCs. I don't really care if it works somehow on mine

Answer (score 0):

At some point in your code, you have to commit the changes. Otherwise they should only appear on your machine. Just add 'commit' to the end, that should do it.

Comment: Unlikely, SQL Server uses implicit transactions which don't need committing.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. Sorry for the wrong answer, then.

Comment: It's possible that the OP is manually starting transactions and not committing of course, but since virtually no information was given, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: You could do a Select with the hint "nolock" to test this.  But unless a trans is explicitly coded/and/"began"....it would auto-commit.  (Unlike Oracle).

Comment: I put commit at the end but nothing changes